# Android SKIA Image Decoding

Tags: android, skia

HI,

I am currently studying how Android decode and image file. When I checked the code, it seems like it is calling the SKIA library. But, how do I know what are the image file format supported by android/skia basing on the source code?

I am not an expert in programming, so I am still trying to understand C++ and Java language.

I am now lost at `SkImageDecoder* decoder = SkImageDecoder::Factory(stream);` inside the BitmapFactory.cpp (JNI file). `SkImageDecoder::Factory(stream)` seems to be a template.

Anyone can explain me what is happening inside `SKImageDecoder::Factory()`? Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
artsylar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the source codes of Android, I think the following image formats are supported.
***ICO (Windows ICON image format), BMP, JPEG, WBMP, GIF, and PNG.***

Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In skia/include/images/SkImageDecoder.h file, there is the image list decoding supported by Skia:

```
enum Format {
    kUnknown_Format,
    kBMP_Format,
    kGIF_Format,
    kICO_Format,
    kJPEG_Format,
    kPNG_Format,
    kWBMP_Format,
    kWEBP_Format,

    kLastKnownFormat = kWEBP_Format
};
```

In SkImageDecoder::Factory(stream) function, it will new a decoder instance according to analyze the Stream's header.

Answer (score 0):

PNG, JPEG, and GIF are the supported formats.  The primary formats used on Android are PNG and JPEG.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Would you know where in the source code android is checking if the file format is supported or not? I am thinking that is being done in 'SkImageDecoder::Factory(stream);' inside the BitmapFactory.cpp(JNI). But I still can't figure where it is specifically done.

Comment: I found the ff classes in SKIA library 
SkFPDFEMBImageDecoder // FPDFEMB   
SkBMPImageDecoder    // BMP File
SkGIFImageDecoder    // GIF file
SkICOImageDecoder    // ICO file?
SkJPEGImageDecoder   // Baseline JPEG Format
SkPNGImageDecoder    // PNG
SkPVJPEGImageDecoder // Progressive JPEG Format ? 
SkWBMPImageDecoder  // Wireless Application Protocol Bitmap Format

Comment: Just to confirm if android uses the classes above, I have tried to display a valid ICO file ('Bitmap bmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/vlc.ico");') and it was properly displayed in the emulator.