# Thrown exception while compressing bitmap inside AsyncTask is not stopping execution

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an `AsyncTask` written in Kotlin that processes a bitmap and the stores it to a file in internal storage. My phone has no free space for the new bitmap, so during the write, an IOException is thrown, which should make the app crash.

This is my `doInBackground()` function:

```
override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Int?): Exception? {
    if(params[0] == null)
        throw IllegalArgumentException();
    Log.d("PhotoEditTask", "start")
    var bitmap : Bitmap? = null
        val degrees = if(params.size == 0) 0 else params[0] ?: 0
        bitmap = BitmapProcessing.getBitmapFromUri(sourceUri, resolver)
        if (bitmap != null) {
            bitmap = BitmapProcessing.rotateBitmap(bitmap, degrees)
            var destFile = File(destPath)
            destFile.delete()
            BitmapFile.saveBitmapToFile(bitmap, destFile, 85)
            Log.d("PhotoEditTask", "save successfull!")
            return null
        }
        bitmap?.recycle()

    return Exception("Write failed")

}
```

and the function that writes the file to a Bitmap is:

```
fun saveBitmapToFile(source: Bitmap, dest: File, quality: Int) {
        var fout : FileOutputStream? = null
        fout = FileOutputStream(dest)
        source.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, quality, fout)
        fout.flush()
        fout.close()
        Log.d("BitmapProcessing", "fout is closed")

    }
```

This should crash, or at the very least return an Exception with the "Write failed" message, but it should never return null since my phone can't write the file. However the log shows otherwise:

```
09-09 12:16:40.824 26074-26805/com.criptext.uisample D/skia: jpeg_decoder finish successfully, L:1881!!!
09-09 12:16:40.833 26074-26805/com.criptext.uisample W/System.err: java.io.IOException: write failed: ENOSPC (No space left on device)
09-09 12:16:40.836 26074-26805/com.criptext.uisample W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:499)
09-09 12:16:40.836 26074-26805/com.criptext.uisample W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:187)
09-09 12:16:40.837 26074-26805/com.criptext.uisample W/System.err:     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCompress(Native Method)
09-09 12:16:40.837 26074-26805/com.criptext.uisample W/System.err:     at android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.java:1013)
09-09 12:16:40.837 26074-26805/com.criptext.uisample W/System.err:     at com.criptext.monkeykitui.util.BitmapFile.saveBitmapToFile(BitmapFile.java:18)
09-09 12:16:40.837 26074-26805/com.criptext.uisample W/System.err:     at com.criptext.monkeykitui.input.photoEditor.PhotoEditTask.doInBackground(PhotoEditTask.kt:42)
09-09 12:16:40.838 26074-26805/com.criptext.uisample W/System.err:     at com.criptext.monkeykitui.input.photoEditor.PhotoEditTask.doInBackground(PhotoEditTask.kt:17)
09-09 12:16:40.838 26074-26805/com.criptext.uisample W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
09-09 12:16:40.838 26074-26805/com.criptext.uisample W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
09-09 12:16:40.839 26074-26805/com.criptext.uisample W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-09 12:16:40.840 26074-26805/com.criptext.uisample W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-09 12:16:40.840 26074-26805/com.criptext.uisample W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:848)
09-09 12:16:40.840 26074-26805/com.criptext.uisample W/System.err: Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: write failed: ENOSPC (No space left on device)
09-09 12:16:40.842 26074-26805/com.criptext.uisample W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.writeBytes(Native Method)
09-09 12:16:40.842 26074-26805/com.criptext.uisample W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.write(Posix.java:202)
09-09 12:16:40.843 26074-26805/com.criptext.uisample W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.write(BlockGuardOs.java:197)
09-09 12:16:40.843 26074-26805/com.criptext.uisample W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:494)
09-09 12:16:40.843 26074-26805/com.criptext.uisample W/System.err:  ... 11 more
09-09 12:16:40.843 26074-26805/com.criptext.uisample D/skia: ------- write threw an exception
09-09 12:16:40.844 26074-26805/com.criptext.uisample D/BitmapToFile: fout is closed
09-09 12:16:40.844 26074-26805/com.criptext.uisample D/PhotoEditTask: save successfull!
09-09 12:16:40.844 26074-26074/com.criptext.uisample D/PhotoEditTask: result: null
```

According to the Log, the `IOException` is thrown and it is caught somewhere, but the execution is never interrupted, so it always returns null. What is going on? How can I handle the `IOException`??

Comment: What outputs "------- write threw an exception"?

Comment: it's also a bit confusing to see code return something of type `Exception` instead of throwing the exception (which would cause an `ExecutionException` to be thrown when you retrieve the results of the AynscTask), you could return a `PhotoEditResult` class or enum instead.

Comment: After doing some googling, the output is from SKIA library that android uses for image decoding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751719/android-skia-image-decoding

Comment: I agree that it is a bit confusing, but I expect it to crash and not return anything at all. my original idea was to catch the `IOException` and return it as a result, but that didn't work either.

Comment: This looks suspicious: 
`Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: write failed: ENOSPC (No space left on device)`

Is your device full and therefore can't write the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Bitmap` class [`compress()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat%2C%20int%2C%20java.io.OutputStream)) intentionally does not throw an exception on failure.

The documentation lists no exceptions for this method, and instead lists the expected return value as:

> Returns: boolean true if successfully compressed to the specified stream.

That is why you see your line of logging output of **"fout is closed"** since no exception is thrown and there is no checking of the boolean result.

The line of code calling `compress()` needs to check the boolean results:

```
if (!source.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, quality, fout)) {
    throw IOException("compression failure")
}
```